# How to pass a jquery variable from one file to another?

Tags: php, jquery

I want to pass a jquery variable from page1.php to page2.php.
For this, I am using hidden form input method.
In page1.php,

```
<form method="POST" action="page2.php" id="myform">
<input type="hidden" id="myField" name="myFieldName">
</form>
```

And the value for this input field is getting from a script:

```
<script>
activeCount = 2; //some value
$("#myField").val(activeCount);
</script>
```

Now in page2.php,

I cant get the variable printed in page2.php.

In page2.php, I am using the below code:

```
<?php
  $myfname = $_POST['myFieldName'];
  echo $myfname;   // I cant get this printed.
?>
```

Please help.
This question is different in the sense, I want to pass the variable from one php file into another, not a js file.

Comment: Copy your question to google!

Comment: `I cant get the variable printed in page2.php.`-> show us code what you used to print it? also you don't have any submit button then how's you are submitting the form?

Comment: how are you submitting your form? I am unable to see any submit button there